# RadChat (Conversational UI) Messages not updated when Datasource changed

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I am facing issue with Chat Control. When I tried to change datasource of control, Messages in Chat UI does not reflect.

I have List of User in listbox. Each User has Observable collection of TextMessages. When User selection changed, I bind datasource to selected user messages. I assume that Chat control will update its UI by selected User messaged. But it is not working.

I tried to clear MessageListItems on selection change, and re-bind datasource to selected user's messages. In this case Chat UI does not show any messages.

For reference I have uploaded my sample project on Google drive.

[Messenger App](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12uZoglYbqu6_ZfunBUb30Yxr8cTZMRWW)

Comment: haven't used telerik control but try passing a new list to clear the messages.

https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radchat/chat-items/messages/listmessage

Comment: I tried all the possible ways. Moreover I have recreated new control on selection change, but its not working. I think it some problem in control itself. I know it should work fine if i notify datasource change or i explicitly clear messages.

Comment: Have you tried providing observable list? To datasource

Comment: Why don’t you post on telerick support?

Comment: I already did and its up to 7 days. One problem with telerik forum is you will not get answer, when you need it. Yesterday I created trail account and posted issue as ticket. Hopefully they will resolve this issue by today. Thanks Asad.